# Unity - EditorGUILayout show hidden element inside Serializable field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am using Unity 2018.3.14f1 and I am trying to create new `ScriptableObject`.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Items;
using System;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Weapon", menuName = "Ingame Item/Weapon")]
public class Weapon : ScriptableObject
{
    public GameObject modelMesh;
    public WeaponType weaponType;
    public SlotType slotType;
    public WeaponTextureMaps[] weaponTextureMaps;


}

[Serializable]
public struct WeaponTextureMaps
{
    public Material material;
    public Texture normalMap;
    public Texture albedoMap;
    public Texture metalicMap;
    public Texture ambientOcullsionMap;
    public bool hasEmission;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Texture emissionMap;
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomEditor(typeof(Weapon))]
public class Weapon_Editor : Editor
{
    Weapon script;
    GameObject model;
    SerializedProperty m_weaponTextureMaps;

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        script = (Weapon)target;
        model = script.modelMesh;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {

        DrawDefaultInspector(); // for other non-HideInInspector fields
        if (GUI.changed)
        {
            if (model.name != script.modelMesh.name)
            {
                model = script.modelMesh;
                int totalMaterials = model.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterials.Length;
                Array.Resize(ref script.weaponTextureMaps, totalMaterials);
                int i = -1;
                foreach (Material mat in model.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterials)
                {
                    i++;
                    script.weaponTextureMaps[i].material = mat;
                }

            }
        }
        int ii = -1;
        foreach(WeaponTextureMaps wtm in script.weaponTextureMaps)
        {
            ii++;
            if (wtm.hasEmission == true)
            {
                script.weaponTextureMaps[ii].emissionMap = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Emission Map", script.weaponTextureMaps[ii].emissionMap, typeof(Texture), true) as Texture;
            }
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

[image]

When I click "Has Emission" the hidden field should appear inside "Element 0" below the button "Has Emission" it self.

However it appears outside of "Element 0" instead to be inside. How Can I fix that ?

How can I make the hidden field to appear inside it's element?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using `DrawDefaultInspector();`

This causes the field not only appearing outside of the `Element 0` but **after all** entries in the Inspector.

---

Instead I would make a proper `CustomPropertyDrawer` for `WeaponTextureMaps`. The huge advantage: You don't have to again implement a custom Editor for everytime you use a `WeaponTextureMaps` field in a script.

```
    [Serializable]
    public struct WeaponTextureMaps
    {
        public Material material;
        public Texture normalMap;
        public Texture albedoMap;
        public Texture metalicMap;
        public Texture ambientOcullsionMap;
        public bool hasEmission;

        public Texture emissionMap;
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(WeaponTextureMaps))]
    public class WeaponTextureMapsDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            var material = property.FindPropertyRelative("material");
            var normalMap = property.FindPropertyRelative("normalMap");
            var albedoMap = property.FindPropertyRelative("albedoMap");
            var metalicMap = property.FindPropertyRelative("metalicMap");
            var ambientOcullsionMap = property.FindPropertyRelative("ambientOcullsionMap");
            var hasEmission = property.FindPropertyRelative("hasEmission");

            var emissionMap = property.FindPropertyRelative("emissionMap");

            // Using BeginProperty / EndProperty on the parent property means that
            // prefab override logic works on the entire property.
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

            // Draw label
            position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

            EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), material);
            position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

            EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), normalMap);
            position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

            EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), albedoMap);
            position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

            EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), metalicMap);
            position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

            EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), ambientOcullsionMap);
            position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

            EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), hasEmission);
            position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

            if (hasEmission.boolValue)
            {
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), emissionMap);
            }

            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
        }

        public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            var hasEmission = property.FindPropertyRelative("hasEmission");

            return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * (hasEmission.boolValue ? 8 : 7);
        }
    }
#endif
```

---

result

[image]

---

For your `Weapon_Editor` I would suggest to not mix `SerializedProperty` with directly accssing and changing values of the `target`. Instead do

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Weapon))]
public class Weapon_Editor : Editor
{
    SerializedProperty model;
    SerializedProperty weaponType;
    SerializedProperty slotType;
    SerializedProperty weaponTextureMaps;

    // Link all script fields
    public void OnEnable()
    {
        model = serializedObject.FindProperty("modelMesh");
        weaponType = serializedObject.FindProperty("weaponType");
        slotType = serializedObject.FindProperty("slotType");
        weaponTextureMaps = serializedObject.FindProperty("weaponTextureMaps");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Draw the Script field
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        {
            EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromScriptableObject((Weapon)target), typeof(Weapon), false);
        }
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

        // load current values into the serialized fields
        serilaizedObject.Update();

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(model);
        }
        // runs everytime the model is changed
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            if(model.objectReferenceValue == null)
            {
                weaponTextureMaps.arraySize = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // get the renderer fromt he SerializedProperty
                var renderer = ((GameObject)model.objectReferenceValue).GetComponent<Renderer>();

                if(renderer == null)
                {
                     weaponTextureMaps.arraySize = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    int totalMaterials = renderer.sharedMaterials.Length;

                    weaponTextureMaps.arraySize = totalMaterials;

                    // set the material references
                    for (var i = 0; i < totalMaterials; i++)
                    {
                        weaponTextureMaps.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).FindPropertyRelative("material").objectReferenceValue = renderer.sharedMaterials[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(weaponType);EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(slotType);

        // Note you have to pass true in order to see sub-fields
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(weaponTextureMaps, true);

        // Note that without that any changes to SerializedProperties does absolutely nothing
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
#endif
```